# Export hierarchy tree in a specific way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a big help.

I have two tables (SubCells and Codes)

[image]

and

[image]

Visually it looks like this (We can count an order)

[image]

And i need to get this final result (with SQL or even a C#)

[image]

How can i do that ? I think i have to add Order column to my SubCells table, but how can i iterate Codes and get groups and codegroups information ? I prepared test environment and i will glad for all help.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/438a6

Thank you

Comment: I've written two blog post ([first](http://sqlsunday.com/2014/03/30/indented-parent-child-hierarchy/) and [second](http://sqlsunday.com/2014/04/06/accumulating-in-a-hierarchy/)) that pretty much do just this. I'm afraid I don't have the time to write a better answer to your question at the time.